# How do I calculate a rectangle around a point(x,y)

Tags: java, geometry

I need to make a rectangle based of a single coordinate.

How can I make a rectangle around a given point(x,y)?

Comment: I'm not sure what "around a point" means.  You need more information than that to define a rectangle: height and width , the plane in which it lies, the angle it makes with x-axis, etc.  There are an infinite number of rectangles that will meet your unclear requirement.

Comment: are we assuming you start from (0,0) to (x,y)?? otherwise the possibilities are endless

Comment: I meant to create a rectangle around the point, making point the center of the rectangle.

Comment: @sweep See my updated answer then.

Answer (score 2):

By clarifying your requirements.

In other words: you could take x,y as upper left corner; and then add whatever deltaX and deltaY. Or you could define x,y to be in the middle of the rectangle.

Meaning: this will turn really easy - when you figured what you want to do!

And seriously: that is what you have to do. It is your project/assignment, so **you** have to define the rules that apply!

And given your comment: so you have x, y; and you want to put a rectangle with dx, dy "around that". That then makes:

```
x1 = x - dx/2;
x2 = x2 + dx;
```

(meaning that x1 is the left and x2 the right end of the rectangle)

Same for Y.

Answer (score 0):

You need more information than that to uniquely define a rectangle.

It cannot be done with just one point.

The normal way is to define one by specifying the coordinates of two diagonally opposite vertexes.

Answer (score 0):

Well suppose your rectangle has height h and breadth b. The simplest way to draw a rectangle on screen would be to create a JFrame:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setBounds(x, y, b, h);
window.getContentPane().add(new CanvasObj());
window.setVisible(true);
```

Note that x,y should be the coordinates from upper left corner of the screen as required in `setBounds()` and most other java graphics operations.